# Replace periods(decimal points) in numbers with commas in pandas using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am using Python and Pandas to try and replace all the decimal points in the numbers in a column with commas, my current attempt is thus:

```
s = pandas.Series([234.00,423.00,536.56])
s.replace(to_replace="[^0-9]*\.[0-9]*$",value=r"\,",regex=True)
```

however it is not working and I am not very good at regex, the desired output would be:

```
new series
234,00
423,00
536,56
```

Comment: `s.astype(str).str.replace('\.', ',')`?

Comment: You know that will make them strings so you can no longer operate with them, right?

Comment: Your regex is incorrect. `[^0-9]` will match _anything that is not a digit_.

Comment: Also, note that `replace` won't even work because you're calling replace on a column of floats (replace is looking for a string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things to note here -

1. You're calling replace on a column of *floats*, performing regex replacement which requires *strings*
2. Your regular expression is incorrect, you should be using lookarounds, and you shouldn't do `[^0-9]` because `^` inside a character class performs negation (will find anything that is *not* a digit).

I'd do this by first converting to string. You'll need to keep the trailing decimals for which `str.format` will help. Afterwards, call `str.replace`.

```
s.apply('{:.2f}'.format).str.replace('\.', ',')

0    234,00
1    423,00
2    536,56
dtype: object
```

Keep in mind that holding data in this format really serves no purpose computationally.